# Import Plug-Ins into Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I just installed (i.e., unzipped) Eclipse Juno.  I'm going through the "Create a Hellow World SWT application" tutorial.

It says that to import the SWT project you open the Import wizard from the main menu via ***File*** > ***Import***..., and select ***Plug-in Development*** > ***Plug-ins and Fragments***.

As far as I can see, however, the Import dialog contains no folder that refers to plug-ins at all.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as described [here](http://www.java-forums.org/eclipse/53817-having-problems-getting-started-eclipse.html), the following steps will work:

- Help -> Install New Software
- Work with: --All Available Sites--
- General Purpose Tools -> Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment
- Click "Next" until you are asked to agree to terms.  Agree, and
  finish.

After installing this plug-in and restarting Eclipse, you will be able to proceed with the tutorial.